# Images not displaying after transfer to temporary site ~username

Tags: media

I had my site running on my local machine w/ DAMP.

I transferred (FTP) to hostgator shared server under my temporary site url http:// Address/~username. Running drupal 6.28.

My images that are under sites/default/files are not displaying.

Here's what I've done

1. Full html was checked
2. Ran update.php
3. Ran Cron
4. File permissions checked and set
5. Cleared cache
6. Reviewed status report to check issues there
7. Added the base_url to my settings.php file
8. updated my template so that it prints the base_url file
9. Checked file system settings
10. Commented out, deleted .htaccess (under files)
11. cleared my cache
12. Site is not in maintenance mode

It seems that if there has been a solution thrown out there, I've tried it. Any solutions someone could provide would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I just re-read the question and realised I misread it before.

Try setting your base path in the .htaccess file and also the base path in the settings.php file. (actually I think I'm confusing myself. I'll leave this here anyway.)

**Previous answer**

Are you talking just image style images or all images?
Can you look in the source of your page and give an example of one of the file paths that is not loading properly?

I know you have stated you have already done some of these, but this is what I would try.

1. Check a few images by looking at their path in the source and checking on the server that they exist in that place.
2. Try going in your browser, directly to one of the files, for example yoursite.com/sites/default/files/yourfile.png or whatever it is.
3. Check permissions of files directory and also the temporary files directory, which must exist and be writable (the status page should alert you to these anyway).
4. Try saving your image styles to force them to regenerate your images, and clearing your caches again.
5. Check files .htaccess
6. Check your watchdog logs for any errors that might be related (any unrelated errors should be investigated too.

Comment: Thanks for the response....I decided to circle back through some of your recommendations. When I went to ~username/sites/default/files/myfile.png I could see the image. That makes me think I could possible apply a Rewrite rule to the .htaccess file to accomodate for the ~username on this temporary server? Only thing, I don't know how to write it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Added the following rewrite rule to the .htaccess file, but did not work? RewriteRule ^/?sites/default/files/(.*) /~username/sites/default/files/$1 [R=301,L]

Comment: Updated my answer after re-reading the question properly.